How to Create a DynuDNS Subdomain Pointing to an Aternos Server?
I’m currently managing a Minecraft server hosted on Aternos, and I would like to create a subdomain using DynuDNS that points directly to my Aternos server.I don’t have a lot of experience with DNS settings, and I’m not entirely sure about the steps required to set this up correctly. Could someone provide a detailed guide on how to achieve this?

For help with DynuDns, have you asked them. For setting up the subdomain, have you asked the host?

I don't think this belongs on Webmasters - I don't think this has much to do with being a Web Master.  I don't know that it would be on topic there, but Superuser.com has a wider audience and are more likely to know about "Aternos".

Looking at https://support.aternos.org/hc/en-us/articles/360026805072-Connect-to-your-server I don't think that you need to use DynuDNS (and I don't think trying to do so even makes sense) - It looks like Aternos provides the Dynamic DNS service for you.    Based on that link, all you need to do is set up a subdomain with a CNAME record pointing to the domain name of your Aternos server.    (Note you need to use a subdomain like "minecraft.example.com" or "myserver.example.com" - you must not use just "example.com" as that does not work properly with CNAME's.
